# Using highlight.js on laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I have Laravel project (similar to tech blog site) and i want to use `highlightjs` on my website, i have followed their tutorial and linked `highlight.pack.js` and my wanted CSS to my website, so i went ahead to try it on my website and created an article, and tried the following code;

```
<pre>
    <code class="html">
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">
    </code>
</pre>
```

But it does not highlight it, it just treats it as a text.
What can be the issue of it? I can provide live website if it's needed.

Answer (score -2):

Did you call `initHighlightingOnLoad()`?

If you want to initialize it manually, just add this where you want to highlight something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```

The CDN-hosted package doesn't have all the languages. If you don't see the language you need in the ["Common" section](https://highlightjs.org/download/), it can be added manually:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/languages/go.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yeah i called initHighlightingOnLoad, by using this code `<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>`

Comment: Can you provide live so I test it ?

Comment: You are using a Html Editor to create your posts right ?

Comment: It's just an text box basically, where you can add text or edit it. Is html editor needed?

Comment: To avoid funny things use a html editor.There you create custom plugin to manage custom tags